# OSX variable assignments giving error

Tags: bash, syntax, parameter-expansion

How is possible that 'delta_oligo_combined.bedgraph' file is in the directory and can't be seen by cat command? OSX typo?

```
$ type=oligo
$ file_type=combined
$ ls delta_oligo_combined.bedgraph
delta_oligo_combined.bedgraph
$ cat delta_$(type)_$(file_type).bedgraph
-bash: file_type: command not found
cat: delta__.bedgraph: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `cat delta_${type}_${file_type}.bedgraph`

Comment: `$(something)` attempts to _execute_ `something` as if it was a command or executable. Is this what you want?

Comment: Ok, I catched the {} typo.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to include *variable* values in a (path) string:

- `${varName}` is how you reference a variable named `varName` - note the delimiters, `{` and `}` (which aren't always needed).
- By contrast, you mistakenly used syntax `$(...)`, which is meant for for embedding the output from *commands* in a string.

  - Therefore, tokens `type` and `file_type` were interpreted as *commands* and executed:

    - `type` happens to be the name of a builtin utility that outputs nothing when called without parameters.
    - `file_type`, on the other hand, is not the name of any existing command, which is why Bash complained (`command not found`).
  - The resulting file path - after the command substitutions were performed - was `delta__.bedgraph` (both command substitutions expanded to the empty string), causing `cat` to report a non-existent file (`No such file or directory`).

See `man bash` for more.